# How to convert Html to Pdf in live brower in the next tap?

Tags: pdf-generation, fpdf, dompdf

I want to convert my html page into `pdf` format, on the net tab in my project. What is the best solution to achieve this? Thanks in advance.
Below is the code that I have so far:

```
include_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

$dompdf->load_html($content);
$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream('sample.pdf');
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to capture dynamic document content and convert to PDF? Or can the document be reconstructed on the server? Can you better describe your layout and content flow? You mention "next tap" and "net tab"? Do you have an HTML tab and a PDF tab. Or does the user "tap" and a PDF is produced?

Comment: It is new tab brother

Comment: Still need a bit more detail about the process. A tab on the same page (HTML+JS tabs)? A browser tab? Does the user have to do anything or should it be rendered at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this library?

jsPDF | http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

It only uses javascript, so you don't need php.

Comment: No i haven,t, i am new to this environmnet